# Edge split to make flat edge not working

Tags: modeling, edges

I've been struggling with this one for a day now.

[image]

[image]

I will have to tackle why all of a sudden everything I put in game is extremely pixelated as well. However the issue I have here is the strange "x" shaped shadow that seams to lead into the handles at the centre. That is directly mirroring the triangulated mesh. In the past with weird artifacts like this usually marking the edge around it sharp and doing edge split modifier works but it is not working here. You can see the cyan lines where I tried to mark sharp edges usually this sort of thing would solve it. I have no idea what alternatives there are to flatten the plane of each drawer. Is it a normals thing? Do I need to fix those in some way too? I'd like to find something else besides Edge Split since it piles onto the mesh making it bigger in size.

Thanks in advance.

[Blender file](http://%09https://simfileshare.net/download/829731/)

Answer (score 1):

The X shaped shadow in your shader might be due to the triangles leading to the inner circle, you could try deleting those triangles and recreating using quads instead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. The program I used to import to game will automatically triangulate and I prefer to control that myself so I do it in blender first. However it looks like I had the wrong edge loop selected and marked around both handles so my bad!! I redid that step and it worked out in the end. Nice flat shaded drawers finally.

Comment: @NStellar okay! Thanks for returning with the answer!